# Filling PHP array with values from a HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to insert specific rows of an HTML table into a PHP array using a checkbox. For some reason only the first column is going into the array. the code i wrote is:

```
if(isset($_GET["key"])) {
    $user_key = $_GET["key"];
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sandwich.sname, description, size, price FROM sandwich     JOIN menu on sandwich.sname = menu.sname WHERE description like ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $search_string);
        $search_string= "%".$user_key."%";
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($sname, $description, $size, $price);

        // Printing results in HTML
        echo "The menu for the given key word is.<br>";
        echo "<table border = '1'>\n";
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$sname</td><td>$description</td><td>$size</td><td>$price</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='order[]' value='$sname'|'$size'|'$price'></td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";
        $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    }
```

I nede all the sname, size and price values in the array order[] but only sname isgoing into it. Someone please suggest what is wrong with the code. I am totally new to PHP.

Comment: $search_string= "%".$user_key."%"; This line should be before binding. Right?

Comment: @Indra, thanks for the comment, but that did not matter. I believe there is a problem with the syntax in checkbox statement. Not sure though!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple of lines the wrong way round:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $search_string);
$search_string= "%".$user_key."%";
```

should be:

```
$search_string= "%".$user_key."%";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $search_string);
```

Also, are any of the field names common between both your `sandwich` and your `menu` tables?  I would recommend modifying your query to state which tables you are referring to:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sandwich.sname, <tablename>.description, <tablename>.size, <tablename>.price FROM sandwich JOIN menu on sandwich.sname = menu.sname WHERE <tablename>.description like ?")) {
```

Comment: Thanks @danmullen, but that did not work. I changed it immediately after i received a comment from Indra.